# How to add a file to the spring boot jar on top level?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am trying to add a file to the top level folder of a spring boot jar.
We have a generic pipeline which deployes artifacts (jar, war, zip) to a cloud environment (cloudfoundry). And for this pipeline to work, the artifact needs to have cloudfoundry's manifest.yml inside on top level.

So i need to have this manifest file inside the final jar of our spring boot application.
I couldn't get it work with the spring-boot-maven-plugin, as it doesn't seem to provide any fitting options.
Unfortunately I think it has to be done with this plugin, because when using the maven-resource-plugin for instance, the additional resource files will always end up inside BOOT-INF/classes.

So maybe someone has an idea how to solve this issue?

PS: We have other projects using Gradle and there it's very easy to solve using the bootJar task. But moving to Gradle won't be possible for this use case

```
bootJar {
    from('manifest.yml') {
        into '/'
    }
}
```

Comment: put that file into `src/main/resources` directory. Should solve the problem..

Comment: Unfortunately not, this way the file will also end up in BOOT-INF/classes alongside all other resources